# Odd, but unoffensive slang or idioms

Tags: slang

I'm putting a character in a book who is replacing all typical swear words, exclamations, or name calling with old fashioned or little known words. For instance, exclaiming "Snails" instead of Damn or "Confound it!" instead of something else. What are some other words that I can use? Any time period is fine.

Comment: This is technically known as [Euphemism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism).

Comment: An alternative model for this is 1982's "A Christmas Story" where the father of the protagonist cursed constantly but with unintelligible syllables. Check it out for other ideas - maybe come up with a unique sound to give your story some color.

Comment: One can always fall back on Nixon's famous "Expletive deleted!"

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for [minced oaths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oaths).

There are lists [here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/minced-oath.html), [here](http://www.thedrantherlair.com/2011/10/minced-oaths/), and [here](http://www.wordnik.com/lists/minced-oaths).

*Note that "'snails" has been used in place of "by God's nails".*

Comment: Very good. I called them mild expletives but yours are better

Answer (score 2):

You could use **Gordon Bennett**. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/gordon-bennett and http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/gordon-bennett.html

Answer (score 2):

I have heard ["Crumbs"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ACrumb) a lot - I just looked up a supposed etymology linking it to Cromwell rather than Christ :)

Another one for Christ is "Crisps!"

Searching for mild expletive I get

"Yikes!"
"Shoot!"
"Zounds!"
"Holy cow!"
"Good heavens!"
"Goodness gracious!"
"My word!"
"Heavens to Betsy!"
"Cookies!"

Comment: +1 for _zounds_, since the O.P. asked for "old-fashioned" swear words.

Answer (score 2):

Never being comfortable with cursing, I find I use a variety of harmless (I think) expletives in the course of a day.

> In frustration:  "Bullfeathers!"
>
> With mild unbelief or incredulity:  "Good night nurse!"
>
> To register surprise:  "My word!"
>
> A non-committal yes:  "Eh, what the hey!"
>
> Haven't use this one in awhile:  "Oh, fudge!"
>
> Said with a measure of incredulity:  "Well, I'll be dipped!", or "Son of a gun!"
>
> Of late, my form of understatement, or, a left-handed compliment:  "Beats a high colonic!"  Or, "Beats a sharp stick in the eye!"
>
> Couldn't care less:  "I couldn't give a rip!"
>
> Not mine, but Flo's, from the TV show *Alice*:  "Mel, kiss my grits!"

Comment: My father would string together multisyllabic city names in lieu of a blast of curse words. His favorite was, "Sacramento California Cincinnati Ohio!" I don't know of anyone else who does that regularly, but, if the O.P. is writing a book with a fictional character, it could be worth introducing a more idiosyncratic way of expressing frustration. If not, though, I'm upvoting this just for _bullfeathers_.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard anyone use *snails* for *damn it*; I have however hear *drat* and *darn it/gosh darn it.*

Other examples:

Friggin'/Freakin'

Holy Crap

Jumpin' Jehoshaphat

Holy cheesesteaks/cannoli

Jeez/Gee whiz

Cripes

Horse/bull puckey

Crikey

Answer (score 0):

Watch Anchorman: "great odin's raven!" & "by the hammer of thor!"

Also, I call people stupid crumbums.

Also, "Shut the front door!" and  "Get the cat out!"

And finally, "I'd like to show her the fifty states!"